# Uniformly at random polynomial

Tags: polynomials, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

We have a polynomial of degree $d$, and multiply it by a polynomial whose coefficients are chosen uniformly at random and its degree is equal to or less than $d$. My question is whether the result is a polynomial with coefficients distributed uniformly?

Comment: What values can the coefficients take? That must be mentioned to give a meaning to "uniformly".

Comment: Say from the field over which this polynomial is defined.

Comment: If this field is infinite (e.g. $\mathbb R$) then what does "uniformly"mean? There is no such thing as a uniform distribution over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: We define this polynomial over field and the coefficients are uniformly at randomly chosen from Zp.

Comment: Dear @user153438, unfortunately I cannot do that, I am not allowed to... But, why you cannot ask anymore? To be honest, I don't see the reasons... I have flagged your previous post so that some moderator can see that and act as MathSE rules. Sorry for not helping too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a polynomial of degree $2d$. Assuming the base field is $\mathbb{Z}_q$, there are $q^{2d+1}$ such polynomials, but you only get $q^{d+1}$ polynomials, so for $d > 0$ the distribution is not going to be uniform.

Comment: How can we make the result uniformly at random polynomial?

Comment: Can evaluate the result at some points (say d points) to obtain Y values. Then for each Y_i pick a value uniformly at random from a Z*_p , and multiply it by Y-i. By doing so, we can have Y's uniformly at random in Z*-p.